# Performance Issues - Allocating several Big Matrixes in a list

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

Dear colleagues I am trying to allocated 349 matrix of approx 387024 elements (17520x11 mxn) in a list withing a loop for.

The code follows this structure

```
loading libraries
query to a database to fetch the number of a product
lsDF<-list()
for (i in 1:length(product_number)){
    querypart_1<-content
    i=as.numeric(product_number[i]) #index
    querypart_2<-content
    Query_total<-str_c(querypart_1,i,querypart_2)
    df<-as.data.table(dbFetch(dbSendQuery(DB, Query_total)) #fetching columns for the specified product
    df<-df %>% #dplyr operations and calculations
    df<-as.matrix(df)
    lsDF[[i]]<-df
}
```

However as you might expect my RStudio breaks if a run the loop. The code works perfectly when I set i=value and I run this one outside the loop.

Do you know a better solution to do this?

Comment: Have you thought of caching your matrices instead of adding them all to a list?

Comment: What do you mean with catching the matrices?

Comment: Caching, not catching. Saving them instead of loading it all into RAM memory, which is limited and may be the reason Rstudio is crashing.

Comment: Hi, 

I have tried to save the files in a .csv file each iteration of the loop as 
           df_matrix<-as.matrix(df)
           file <- as.character(paste("df_", i, ".csv", sep="")) 
           write.csv(df_matrix, file) 

But it crash around the 69 csv file.

Comment: Anything special about that iteration? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Anything special @csgroen . Finally I made it work after trying several times it brokes 5 times (reaching the file 217 at maximum) and the last trial reached the 349. But the most annoying thing is that I load the files in a list using the code below:

```
ldf <- list() # creates a list
listcsv <- dir(pattern = "*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(product_number)){
    ldf[[i]]<-read_csv(listcsv[i],col_types = cols(X1 = col_skip(), X2 = col_date(format = "%F"), X3 = col_datetime(format = "%F %T"), X4 = col_integer()))
}
```

And the size was only 1.5 GB. I have 16GB of RAM and the R memory limiter is 16GB as well so I do not understand what is going on.